# How do I align text next to other centered text

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have two pieces of text. I need the first piece to be centered horizontally and vertically, and the second to just be right next to it. Currently the code looks like this:

```
<View style={styles.runningTimeWrapper}>
  <Text style={styles.loggedTime}>00:00</Text>
  <Text style={[styles.loggedTime, styles.loggedSeconds]}>00</Text>
</View>
```

How can I style it so the 00:00 is centered? Using fixed widths is not an option as I need this to work on any screen size.

Here is how it looks currently:

[image]

Styles:

```
  loggedTime: {
    color: Variables.PURPLE,
    fontSize: 44,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  loggedSeconds: {
    fontSize: 22,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    paddingBottom: 8
  },

  runningTimeWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
```

The desired effect is to have the column of hh:mm aligned with the center of the screen, and the seconds directly next to the minutes.

On all 'center' references, I am talking about horizontal center (x-axis), not vertical(y-axis) (which is set using alignItems /self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the second span to `position:absolute`, so it will be out of the normal content flow, and ensure the hour/minute to be centered in the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.hm {
  font-size: 44px;
}
.s {
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="hm">12:34</span>
  <span class="s">56</span>
</div>
```

---

In fact, you don't really need flexbox, the `text-align:center` is probably enough to do it.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.hm {
  font-size: 44px;
}
.s {
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="hm">12:34</span>
  <span class="s">56</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need 3 inner wrapper views: an empty one on the left and then wrap the small and big numbers in their own wrapper each. Then give the left and right wrappers flex: 1 to make them the same width.

https://rnplay.org/apps/hLBFng

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand what you're going for. Are you trying to get the `loggedTime` to be perfectly centered and the `loggedSeconds` to be offset to the right of that? Or are you simply trying to get both to be center/center?

I think I was able to get something going here by setting `flexDirection: 'row'` and adding some `paddingTop` to the seconds.

Here's a [demo on rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org/apps/uhvtOQ)

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
 loggedTime: {
    color: '#FF5500',
    fontSize: 44,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  loggedSeconds: {
    fontSize: 22,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 8
  },

  runningTimeWrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: By having justifyContent center on runningTimeWrapper then the sum of time and seconds will be centered. What I try to do is the time to be centered, and the seconds next to it. I added some clarification on the end of the question

Comment: I think the other two answers by alexp and Pangloss look like they'd work out.